# Fairytale/fable/parable about a dog trying to run to a monastery that's rung its bell

Tags: identification-request, folk-tales

The story goes like this: A dog hears the monastery ring its bell, which indicates that there will be food there. So he runs up the hill leading to the monastery. When he's about halfway there, he hears another bell, this time from a different monastery...so he runs down that hill and runs up another hill that leads to the new monastery. He did this a few times, interrupting his journey and switching routes multiple times.

I honestly don't remember how the story ended, but it might have just ended with the dog getting really tired and not getting any food for that day.

I had a few Hans Christian Andersen story collections so I thought this story came in one of those. But none of the AI could give me an answer, so I thought I'd ask here.

Do you know the name of the story? I want to find it again and read it again.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. Please read the [tag wiki for identification requests](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) and [edit your question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/posts/26318/edit) to add further details based on the suggestions there. For example, when and where did you read the story? In what language? Was the story originally in that language, or translated? What other stories were in that collection? What was the physical book like? Any such information will help narrow down the story. Thanks!